# Broad match modifier Excel formula

Tags: google-sheets, libreoffice

Broad match modifier Excel formula

```
="+"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," "," +")
```

doesn´t seem to work in Google Sheets and LibreOffice. Every time I try, getting an error message. In LibreOffice error 501, In Google Sheets #ERROR. I use both in finnish language, so I have changed SUBSTITUTE for the finnish equivalent, still the same error...

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Perhaps they want a semicolon instead of a comma?

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch on the iterative setting in Google Sheets, now is working fine, thanks.